# Python: replace multiple values of a Matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
M = [[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I want to replace the values from M[1][2] to M[2][3] with an x
So that the matrix looks like this:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, "x", "x"], ["x", "x", "x", "x"], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: yeah both answers are working nice, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
M = [[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
x=1

while (x<=2):
    if (x==1):
        y=2
    else:
        y=0
    while (y<=3):
        M[x][y]="x"
        y+=1
    x+=1
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, "x", "x"], ["x", "x", "x", "x"], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
startIndexX = 1
startIndexY = 2
endIndexX = 2
endIndexY = 3

x = startIndexX
firstLoop = True
while (x<=startIndexY):
    y=endIndexX
    if(not firstLoop):
        y=0
    while (y<=endIndexY):
        M[x][y]="x"
        y+=1
    x+=1
    firstLoop = False
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```